# Magento2: How to add data in child table?

Tags: magento2, collection, model, resource-model

I have a custom module with named **A** and db tab is **z** ok.
**now question is my:**

1. How to add child table? which is already I have done with PK and FK key constrains.
2. How to add data in created child table using model?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below code.

```
    protected $_orderTemplate;
    protected $_orderTemplateItem;
   
    public function __construct(
      .....
        \Bhavesh\OrderTemplate\Model\OrderTemplate $orderTemplate,
        \Bhavesh\OrderTemplate\Model\OrderTemplateItem $orderTemplateItem,
      ....
    ) {
        .....
        $this->_orderTemplate = $orderTemplate;
        $this->_orderTemplateItem = $orderTemplateItem;
        .....
    }


   public function execute()
    {
         // Parent table
          $template_name = $templateName."-".date('M Y');
          $CartTotalQty=10;
          $CartGrandTotal=1000;
          $CartSubtotal=1100;
          $orderTemplateModel->setTemplateName($template_name)
           ->setOrderSubtotal($CartSubtotal)
           ->setOrderGrandtotal($CartGrandTotal)
           ->setOrderedQty($CartTotalQty)
           ->setCustomerId($_customerid);
          $orderTemplateModel->save(); 
           // parent table id    
          $templateID = $orderTemplateModel->getTemplateId();
          // Child Table store in Product data   
          $orderTemplateItemModel = $this->_orderTemplateItem;
          $orderTemplateItemModel->setTemplateId($templateID)
                     ->setProductName($product->getName())
                     ->setProductId($product->getProductId())
                     ->setProductSku($product->getSku())
                     ->setProductQty($product->getQty())
                     ->setProductPrice($product->getPrice());
          $orderTemplateItemModel->save();;
    }
```